# Postgres replication ERROR reorderbuffer spill

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgres-10

I have setup postgres logical replication that work well for short time.
now i see that the replication status is: 'catchup',
and the following error in mater log:
"ERROR:  could not read from reorderbuffer spill file: Not enough space"
on the master drive there is 500GB free, so i assume it is not space issue
any idea?

Comment: Were you closely monitoring free space **at the time the error was thrown**?

Comment: this happen when full vacuum is running manually, any suggestion to prevent this, maybe disable logical replication prior to running vacuum?

Comment: How big is the table you are doing the vacuum full on?  If vacuum full is filling up your hard drive, and then failing and rolling back and automatically freeing up the space again, then it could cause any number of things to fail while you had a transient out of space condition.  If it isn't logical replication, it will just be something else next time.  (Did the vacuum full also fail?)

Comment: we have some big size tables like 70gb and 50gb, this week we saw this error before postgres on  master hangs-
 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.errors.OutOfMemory) out of memory
DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 48. 

disk space is no issue

Comment: Those seem like independent things, out of memory and out of (disk) space.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes. we decide to disable manual full vacuum for now.